# Rails 2.3.5 Mime::Type in environment.rb works for server but not console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types

To support a KML mime type I have this line in my environment.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml', :kml
```

It seems to work just fine on the server. I can use .kml as a format in respond_to blocks and everything is OK. Without that line I cannot.

However, when I try to run the console now on the same environment I get an error on that line:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Mime
```

I did restart the server after modifying environment.rb.

I'm confused as to why the difference between the server and console and what I'm doing wrong with the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered this works for both the server and console if it is added to  /initializers/mime_types.rb instead of environment.rb. I do not know why the console/server discrepancy existed but it seems this is the intended place anyway.